# Bind to Property of First Item in EntityCollection: Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have an entity called BetaTestDevice it has an EntityCollection property called BetaLogData. I have a GridView displaying details about the BetaTestDevice. My users would like to be able to display the FirmwareVersion from the most recent BetaLogData entry in said GridView. Were this any other type of collection I could use

```
Text="{Binding BetaLogData[0].FirmwareVersion}"
```

How might I do this with an EntityCollection? I have tried a converter but the object value parameter that seems to be passed is a BetaLogDatum (singular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this using a value converter. I was improperly handling nulls.